# SelectAll checkbox to check only specific column

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a somewhat working version of a datagrid with 2 columns of checkbox, 1 SelectAll checkbox in the header of second column. The issue right now is when I click the SelectAll, it will check/uncheck all checkbox in the datagrid.

I would like to have the SelectAll checkbox only check/uncheck the column it is in. Can someone help me on this? Thanks!

JavaScript

```
function SelectAllCheckboxesSpecific(spanChk) {
    var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
    var Chk = spanChk;
    Parent = document.getElementById('dgPicsUploaded');
    var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].id != Chk && items[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (items[i].checked != IsChecked) {
                items[i].click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataGrid

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="50px" />
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveItemID" runat="server" Text="Save Item ID" OnClick="btnSaveItemID_Click" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="select2" runat="server" Checked="false"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
...............
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="30px" />
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxSelectAll" Text="Select All" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxesSpecific(this);"></asp:CheckBox>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="select" runat="server" Checked="false"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: hmmm  can you give me a bit more detailed answer? I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: Strangely, all the existing answers I could find are based on jQuery, gridview or some other library or framework, so I've added a POJS version. The only hard part is getting the column index, after that it's just a selector with *forEach*.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the "select all" checkbox is in the same column as the checkboxes it applies to, you can get the *cellIndex* of its parent cell, then use that to find and check the checkboxes in the same column. A selector will likely do the job, if not a loop over the relevant rows getting the checkbox in the `row.cells[index]` checkbox.

Note that *cellIndex* is zero based, but *nth-child* starts at 1 so you need to add 1 to the index.

```js
// Get nearest ancestor with tagName at or above node
function getNearest(tagName, node) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  while (node && node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() != tagName) {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return node && node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName? node : null;
}

function checkAllInCol(evt) {
  var node = this;
  var cell = getNearest('th', node);
  if (!cell) return;
  var selector = `td:nth-child(${cell.cellIndex+1})`;
  var table = getNearest('table', cell);
  table.tBodies[0].querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(
    cell => cell.querySelector('input').checked = node.checked
  );
}

window.onload = function() {
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll('th input').forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', checkAllInCol, false);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th><label>Col 0: <input type="checkbox"></label>
        <th><label>Col 1: <input type="checkbox"></label>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"><td><input type="checkbox"> 
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"><td><input type="checkbox"> 
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"><td><input type="checkbox">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You should add error checking and validation, e.g. make sure `cell.querySelector('input')` returns a node before assigning to its *checked* property.

Comment: PS. Be careful with *NodeList.forEach*, it was added recently and may not be supported everywhere. An alternative is a plain loop or `Array.from(NodeList).forEach(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I end of using a bit of a cheat way to solve the issue. In my IF validation, I added the following && items[i].id.toString().indexOf("select2") == -1

Comment: @joseph.c—if you're going to use that approach, it would be much better to give them a class and select them using that, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('.select2').forEach((el, i, list) => el.checked = list[0].checked)`.